# Minimize $\prod_{i=1}^3(x_{i1}+x_{i2}+x_{i3}) \prod_{j=1}^3 (\frac{c_{1j}}{x_{1j}} + \frac{c_{2j}}{x_{2j}} + \frac{c_{3j}}{x_{3j}})$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $c_{ij}$ ($1\le i,j\le 3$) be positive constants and $x_{ij}$ ($1\le i,j\le 3$) be positive variables. Find the minimum value of
\begin{equation}
(x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13})(x_{21}+x_{22}+x_{23})(x_{31}+x_{32}+x_{33})
\left(\frac{c_{11}}{x_{11}} + \frac{c_{21}}{x_{21}} + \frac{c_{31}}{x_{31}}\right)
\left(\frac{c_{12}}{x_{12}} + \frac{c_{22}}{x_{22}} + \frac{c_{32}}{x_{32}}\right)
\left(\frac{c_{13}}{x_{13}} + \frac{c_{23}}{x_{23}} + \frac{c_{33}}{x_{33}}\right).
\end{equation}

This is a $3\times 3$ extension of a previous [$2\times 2$ problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4327621/31498).

**(The following part has been updated for clarifications)**

Applying Hölder inequality we can obtain the following 3 lower bounds:

\begin{align}
L_1 &= \left(\sqrt[6]{c_{11}c_{22}c_{33}} + \sqrt[6]{c_{12}c_{23}c_{31}} + \sqrt[6]{c_{13}c_{21}c_{32}}\right)^6,\\
L_2 &=\left(\sqrt[6]{c_{11}c_{23}c_{32}}  + \sqrt[6]{c_{12}c_{21}c_{33}}  + \sqrt[6]{c_{13}c_{22}c_{31}}\right)^6,\\
L_3 &= \left(\sqrt[6]{c_{11}c_{22}c_{33}} + \sqrt[6]{c_{12}c_{23}c_{31}} + \sqrt[6]{c_{13}c_{21}c_{32}}\right)^3\left(\sqrt[6]{c_{11}c_{23}c_{32}}  + \sqrt[6]{c_{12}c_{21}c_{33}}  + \sqrt[6]{c_{13}c_{22}c_{31}}\right)^3.
\end{align}
That last is obviously a consequence of the first two. The best lower bound so far is thus $\max(L_1,L_2)$, but it is not the actual minimum value.

The above results can be obtained by suitably rearranging the terms and applying Hölder inequality, as shown below.
\begin{align}
(x_{11}+x_{12}+x_{13})(x_{22}+x_{23}+x_{21})(x_{33}+x_{31}+x_{32})
 &\ge \left(\sqrt[3]{x_{11}x_{22}x_{33}} + \sqrt[3]{x_{12}x_{23}x_{31}} + \sqrt[6]{x_{13}x_{21}x_{32}}\right)^3\\
\left(\frac{c_{11}}{x_{11}} + \frac{c_{21}}{x_{21}} + \frac{c_{31}}{x_{31}}\right)
\left(\frac{c_{32}}{x_{32}} + \frac{c_{12}}{x_{12}} + \frac{c_{22}}{x_{22}}\right)
\left(\frac{c_{33}}{x_{33}} + \frac{c_{13}}{x_{13}} + \frac{c_{23}}{x_{23}}\right) 
&\ge \left(\sqrt[3]{ \frac{c_{11}c_{22}c_{33}}{x_{11}x_{22}x_{33}}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{c_{12}c_{23}c_{31}}{x_{12}x_{23}x_{31}}} + \sqrt[6]{\frac{c_{13}c_{21}c_{32}}{x_{13}x_{21}x_{32}}}\right)^3
\end{align}
Multiply the above two inequalities and applying Cauchy-Swcharz inequality we obtain the lower bound $L_1$. And $L_2$ can be obtained in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Macavity That doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: @Macavity You've probably misread the last 3 terms. The first 3 are along the rows and the last 3 are along the columns.

Comment: Just noticed the difference in ordering. How did you apply Holder - this doesn't look amenable to Holder either.

Comment: @Macavity Please see the update.